# Updating tableview rows with map as data for two columns by setCellFactory

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, tableview

In my tableview class-model i have some java.util.Map attribute. Two of my table columns must filling by string values, which getted after some calculations with Map attribute. Also, these two colums can contains button(not string) in some cases. Now i'm trying to update my table by %columnName%.setCellFactory(Callback callback) method. 
P.S. My solution is successful in a sense. After updating, when i double-click on a tablecell - it's updating. So my tableview knows what value my cell must contains.

UPD: Part of my model:

```
class AppServerParameter{

    private Map<String, Map<Integer, AppServerParameterValue>> actualValues;
    public Map<String, Map<Integer, AppServerParameterValue>> getActualValues() {
        return actualValues;
    }

    public void setActualValues(Map<String, Map<Integer, AppServerParameterValue>> actualValues) {
        this.actualValues = actualValues;
    }
}
```

And setCellFactory method:

```
value = new TableColumn("Value");
        value.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn param) {
                return new TableCell() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        try {
                            if (getTableRow() != null && getTableRow().getIndex() >= 0) {
                                if(getIndex()>getTableView().getItems().size()-1) return;
                                final AppServerParameter appServerParameter = (AppServerParameter) getTableView().getItems().get(getTableRow().getIndex());
                                if (appServerParameter.isLevelled()==null) {
                                    setGraphic(new Label("Not received"));
                                } else if (appServerParameter.isLevelled()) {
                                    setGraphic(new Label(appServerParameter.getVeryFirstValue().getValue()));
                                } else {
                                    Button button = new Button("Different values");
                                    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                                            Stage modal = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
                                            modal.setTitle(appServerParameter.getName() + " values");
                                            modal.setScene(new DifferencesWindow(new ScrollPane(), 500, 500, appServerParameter.getActualValues()));
                                            modal.show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    setGraphic(button);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                };
            }
        });
```

UPD2: Also, i'm trying to update my table manualy. This method works with JavaFX8, but not with JavaFX 2.2:

```
TableView<AppServerParameter> tableView = (TableView) node;
                final List<AppServerParameter> items=new LinkedList<AppServerParameter>();
                FXCollections.copy(tableView.getItems(), items);
                tableView.getItems().removeAll();
                tableView.getItems().addAll(items);
```

Comment: Can you post some code, especially of your model? Does the model use JavaFX properties? Are the values in the model changing at runtime?

Comment: private Map<String, Map<Integer, AppServerParameterValue>> actualValues;

public Map<String, Map<Integer, AppServerParameterValue>> getActualValues() {
        return actualValues;
    }

public void setActualValues(Map<String, Map<Integer, AppServerParameterValue>> actualValues) {
        this.actualValues = actualValues;
    }

These field in in my model. I don't use properties.

And my cellFactory from the tableview: http://pastebin.com/FqkJaZ3z

Comment: Can you put that in your question; it's not really readable in a comment.

Comment: Sorry for delay, i've updated my question.

Comment: You should have a `cellValueFactory`, which determines the data the cell is displaying, in addition to a `cellFactory` (which determines how to display it). But if the underlying data are changing external to the table itself, you will need to use JavaFX properties so the table can observe these and respond to changes.